# In C++, do I need to create my own stack or queue class or can I import it from somewhere?

Tags: c++, stl, stack, queue

everything that I've seen online describes the implementation for a stack.cpp file and how to include a stack.h file that uses your own implementation. When I use a stack or queue in python it is simply:

```
from queue import *
```

I don't care how to implement a stack or queue, I just need to use one. What is the above python code equivalent in C++? Or do I really have to implement my own stacks and queues here?

Comment: I dont get how this question made it past google...

Comment: My searches were for "#include <stack.h>" and "#include <queue.h>". Most of these result in implementation advice. Searching "include stack" gives the correct advice, which I didn't consider until I saw the answers here. I know this may seem like a trivial question to you, but the right way of phrasing a search is not obvious to a complete beginner. The answers here really helped, and I'm sure they will help another beginer who is searching stack.h instead of stack. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are container adapters `std::stack`, `std::queue` and `std::priority_queue` in C++. They are declared correspondingly in headers `<stack>` and `<queue>`. All you need is to include the appropriate header. For example

```
#include <stack>
```

Answer (score 2):

The C++ Standard Library provides various container classes, including [the stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) and the [queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
```

will give you

```
std::stack<T>
```

and

```
std::queue<T>
```

respectively

Answer (score 0):

Following operations are allowed in stack

empty, size, back, push_back, pop_back

Exmaple for stack

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <stack>          // std::stack

int main ()
{
  std::stack<int> mystack;

  for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) mystack.push(i);

  std::cout << "Popping out elements...";
  while (!mystack.empty())
  {
     std::cout << ' ' << mystack.top();
     mystack.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Following operations are allowed in queue

empty, size, front, back, push_back, pop_front

Example for queue

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cin, std::cout
#include <queue>          // std::queue

int main ()
{
  std::queue<int> myqueue;
  int myint;

  std::cout << "Please enter some integers (enter 0 to end):\n";

  do {
    std::cin >> myint;
    myqueue.push (myint);
  } while (myint);

  std::cout << "myqueue contains: ";
  while (!myqueue.empty())
  {
    std::cout << ' ' << myqueue.front();
    myqueue.pop();
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

For more details and examples

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/